# File created in git by copying contents from other has the original file history

Tags: java, git, github

One of my teammates created a java file by copying from another file. Guess, what the new file looks like an edit over the original file in git repository . The two files are completely different and I want the new file to have its own history not copied history. The pull request shows the file is copied and has history of changes associated with it. Does anyone know how to remove this history associated with copying? The is wanted behavior done through git

Comment: Can you give the exact commands to reproduce this?

Comment: Copy a file from from folder /src/somepackage to src/anotherpage and rename the file. It will detect that it is a copy and will have history

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15031576/2570538

Comment: I tried exactly this, and could not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In Git, files do not have history.  History is attached to *commits*: commits have parent commits, which have more parents, and so on.  Each of these commits has an ID (a "true name" SHA-1 hash), and author and committer (name, email, time-stamp), and log message as well.

Of course, everyone wants to see file history.  So Git fakes it up: it compares one historical commit to another newer commit, diffing all the files in each commit.  When it diffs the files, it may decide that the earlier commit's `dir/README.txt` was copied or renamed to the new commit's `python/sourcefile.py`.  It will therefore tell you that the "history" of `python/sourcefile.py` is that it was `dir/README.txt` before.

That history is *completely imaginary*, unless you don't want it to be, in which case, it is the *utter, absolute truth!*  It's your decision whether to believe Git.

You also get some control knobs:

- `diff.renames`: if `true`, ask Git to detect renamed files.  If `false`, ask Git not to detect renames.  If `copies`, ask Git to detect copied files as well as renamed files.  The default is now `true` but was `false` in older (pre-2.9) versions of Git.
- `diff.renameLimit`: how *many* files should Git treat as candidates for rename detection.  Rename and copy detection is somewhat slow and memory-intensive so Git used to have a limit of 500, then 1000, then 2000, as its defaults here.  Setting this to 0 means "as many as Git can manage."
- `diff.algorithm` (and many external diff driver configuration options): see [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Besides these, there are command-line switches for the same items, plus a "match threshold" (`-M`) value that defaults to "50% similar": files at least "50% similar" were renamed, files less than "50% similar" were not.

(Note that some commands, such as `git merge`, run their internal `git diff`-s with some of these settings set differently from their defaults.  There are controls for these as well.)

#### If the file has the same pathname

In your case, it sounds like what happened was:

- An older commit, call it `$OLD`, had file `src/foo.java`.
- Somewhere along the way `src/foo.java` was removed entirely (and committed, or not committed, it won't matter here).
- Then later someone wrote a new, or copied something else to, `src/foo.java`, and committed; call this `$NEW`.
- Now comparing `$OLD` to `$NEW` insists on comparing the unrelated files.

Here you are semi-stuck: Git believes that since `src/foo.java` and `src/foo.java` have the *same name*, it should *compare their contents*.  However, there's one more control knob, as [`git diff` has a `-B` switch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> `-B[<n>][/<m>], --break-rewrites[=[<n>][/<m>]]`
>
> Break complete rewrite changes into pairs of delete and create.
>              This serves two purposes:
>
> It affects the way a change that amounts to a total rewrite of a
>              file not as a series of deletion and insertion mixed together with
>              a very few lines that happen to match textually as the context, but
>              as a single deletion of everything old followed by a single
>              insertion of everything new, and the number ***m*** controls this aspect
>              of the `-B` option (defaults to `60%`).  `-B/70%` specifies that less
>              than 30% of the original should remain in the result for Git to
>              consider it a total rewrite (i.e. otherwise the resulting patch
>              will be a series of deletion and insertion mixed together with
>              context lines).
>
> When used with `-M`, a totally-rewritten file is also considered as
>              the source of a rename (usually `-M` only considers a file that
>              disappeared as the source of a rename), and the number ***n*** controls
>              this aspect of the `-B` option (defaults to 50%).  `-B20%` specifies
>              that a change with addition and deletion compared to 20% or more of
>              the file's size are eligible for being picked up as a possible
>              source of a rename to another file.

So, by supplying `-B` and turning on rename and copy detection, you may get the output you want.