# How to make git think a file was renamed

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm reviewing someone's pull request on GitHub and quite a few files turn out to be copies of old deleted files. How can I tell git/GitHub that those are new versions of old files so I can view the diffs only and not the whole contents of the files?

To some extent, it's the opposite of what was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031576/how-can-i-prevent-git-from-thinking-i-did-a-rename).

Comment: You can't control GitHub, but you can control git on the command line, by following the steps in highest rated answer in the question that you linked to.

Comment: Git has no concept of file histories.

Comment: Was the deleted (and copied back) files tracked by git once?

Comment: @Arount - yes, I ended up creating a new branch, renaming (`git mv`) and copying the files over from the PR.